# Numero primo en java

Tags: java

tengo una tarea de introducir si un numero es primo o no. Llevo algo avanzado pero no puedo utilizar contadores ni bucles(restricción de la profesora) por que no hemos visto esos temas. Alguien me puede dar una señal de que puedo hacer.

```
import java.util.*;  // Biblioteca que permite el uso de caracteres, numeracion

public class NumeroPrimo
{ // Inicio

    public static void main (String[] args)
    { // Inicio

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Ingrese un número: ");
    int numPrimo = sc.nextInt();

    if(numPrimo%1 == 0 && numPrimo%numPrimo == 0)
    { // Inicio primer if
        System.out.println("Es primo");
    } // Fin primer if
    else
        System.out.println("No es primo");
    }
    //else if(numPrimo/numPrimo<numPrimo){
        //System.out.println("No es primo");
    //} // Fin segundo if

} //Fin
```

Comment: Desconozco como hacer lo que queres, sin usar un contador o un bucle.. sabes como saber si un numero es primo o no? hay formulas matematicas para saber si uno es primo o no.. pero no creo que esa sea la idea tampoco...

Comment: La única manera que se me ocurre sin la utilización de un bucle o un contador es mediante un método recursivo, pero no creo que eso tampoco sea la idea. A lo mejor dicha restricción es para probar algún punto de que no se puede hacer sin las estructuras de control que aún no les han mostrado.

Comment: definitivamente te esta pidiendo métodos recursivos

Answer (score 1):

Sin la utilización de bucles o contadores se me ocurrió esta manera. El aux es una copia del numero que se busca saber si es primo o no.

```
public static int funcionPrimos(int numPrimo, int aux) {

    if (aux > 0) {
        if(numPrimo % aux == 0)
            return 1+funcionPrimos(numPrimo, aux-1);
        return funcionPrimos(numPrimo, aux-1);

    }else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Si retorna 2 es porque es primo. Por ejemplo:

```
int numPrimo = 89;

            if(funcionPrimos(numPrimo, numPrimo) == 2)
                System.out.println("Es primo");
            else
                System.out.println("No es primo");
```

Output: Es primo